# onmouseover for SVG Group

Tags: svg, onmouseover

I'm an SVG novice trying to work things out...

I'm attempting to create an SVG element - a black 'i' in a white circle, that inverts on mouse over (i.e., becomes a white 'i' in a black circle).

I have this:

```html
<svg>
<g id="g3794"
 onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', 'red');"
 onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');"
 cursor="help"
 class="info">
 <title id="title4601">Test Title</title>
 <circle style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.18795563" transform="scale(1,-1)" r="2.3912315" cy="-126.73662" cx="55.64901" id="path86" class="info_circle" />
 <text transform="scale(1,-1)" id="text84" y="-125.03816" x="55.623314"
  style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:5.01215029px;line-height:3.75911283px;font-family:'Times New Roman';-inkscape-font-specification:'Times New Roman, ';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.18795563"
  xml:space="preserve"
  class="info_i">
   <tspan style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;stroke-width:0.18795563" y="-125.03816" x="55.623314" id="tspan82" sodipodi:role="line">i</tspan>
 </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

I notice:

- The group mouse over for the cursor change (to help) activates on the circle
- But the group mouse over for the colour change only activates on, and works on, the text

How can I get the effect I want? I could set hover styles in CSS for both element classes, but that would only work for each element individually. How do I change the colour of both group elements when either is the hover target?

Comment: the `g`'s `fill` attribute has less importance than its children's `style="fill:color"`. But is there a reason you want to do it through js instead of [doing it with css](https://jsfiddle.net/a9zquykm/)?

Comment: But the fill style is set for both children - why does g override one and not the other? Anywa, I don't mind how it's done, except I was trying to keep in inside the SVG file...the CSS way looks promising, thanks.

Comment: Because `evt.target` is your `<tspan>`. You can very well append the css in a SVGStyle element inside your svg file (`<svg ...><defs><style>your CSS</style></defs><g>..`)

Comment: I got it working with CSS in the file...thanks!